# How can I proof the binomial formula by using the generating function of $q_m$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

The authors give the generating function of the generalized Fibonacci polynomial and they proof the Theorem 2.4 in (http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~giacomo.dellariccia/Glossary/Lucas/NalliHaukkanen2009.pdf) 
    \begin{eqnarray}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{h,n}(x)t^n &=& \frac{t}{1-\left( h(x)t + t^2 \right)} = t \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( h(x)t +t^2 \right)^n \nonumber \\
  & = &t \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \left( h(x)t \right)^{n-i} \left(t^2\right)^i \nonumber \\
  & = & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} h^{n-i}(x)t^{n+i+1}. \nonumber
 \end{eqnarray}
    Writing $n+i+1=m$, they obtain
    \begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{h,n}(x)t^n =  \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left[ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{m-1}{2} \rfloor} \binom{m-i-1}{i} h^{m-2i-1} \right] t^m. \nonumber
 \end{equation}
    Thus, they extract the binomial formula from the above equation and they get 
    \begin{equation}
   F_{h,n}(x) =  \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{m-1}{2} \rfloor} \binom{m-i-1}{i} h^{m-2i-1}. \nonumber
 \end{equation} 
    Now, we have a generating function
    \begin{equation}
 F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q_n x^n = \frac{x \left( 1+ax-x^2 \right)}{1- (ab+2)x^2 + x^4} \nonumber.
 \end{equation}
    The authors give the binomial formula with Theorem 2 in ( http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300310012403 ) as
    \begin{equation}
  q_m = a^{\xi(m-1)} \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor \frac{m-1}{2} \rfloor } \binom{m-k-1}{k} \left( ab \right)^{\lfloor \frac{m-1}{2} \rfloor -k} \nonumber
 \end{equation}
    How can I proof the binomial formula of $q_m$ by using the generating function $F(x)$ similar to first proof? The authors proved it by using induction method but I will not use induction while prooving it.
    Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A derivation similar to that of $F_{h,n}(x)$ does  not  directly lead to the wanted binomial expression for $q_m$  but instead to another one. In a second step equality of these binomial expressions will be shown.

**First step:**

We consider the generating function
\begin{align*}
F(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty q_nx^n=\frac{x(1+ax-x^2)}{1-(ab+2)x^2+x^4}\\
&=x+ax^2+(ab+1)x^3+a(ab+2)x^4+(a^2b^2+3ab+1)x^5+\cdots\\
\end{align*}
and want to show
\begin{align*}
q_m&=[x^m]F(x)\\
&=a^{\frac{1+(-1)^m}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\right\rfloor}
\binom{m-k-1}{k}(ab)^{\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\right\rfloor-k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty q_nx^n=\frac{x(1+ax-x^2)}{1-(ab+2)x^2+x^4}\\
> &=x(1+ax-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left((ab+2)x^2-x^4\right)^n\\
> &=x(1+ax-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}((ab+2)x^2)^{n-k}(-x^4)^k\\
> &=(1+ax-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{n-k}x^{2n+2k+1}\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}

In order to obtain $q_m$, the coefficient of $x^m$ of $F(x)$, it is convenient to consider even and odd case separately. When considering in (2) the factor $(1+ax-x^2)$ we see that even powers of $x$ are given when taking the term $ax$, while odd powers are obtained when taking the other two terms $1-x^2$.

> **Even powers: $m=2m^{\prime}$**
>
> We obtain by considering even powers in (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{2m^{\prime}}]F(x)&=a[x^{2m^{\prime}}]\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{n-k}x^{2n+2k+2}\\
> &=a\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m^{\prime}-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{m^{\prime}-k-1}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{m^{\prime}-2k-1}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   Here we have $2m^\prime=2n+2k+2$ which implies $m^\prime=n+k+1$ and the upper bound of the sum is derived from the binomial coefficient which gives $k\leq m^{\prime}-k-1$, resp. $k\leq \frac{m^{\prime}-1}{2}$.
>
> **Odd powers: $m=2m^{\prime}+1$**
>
> We obtain by considering odd powers in (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{2m^{\prime}+1}]F(x)&=[x^{2m^\prime+1}]\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{n-k}x^{2n+2k+1}\\
> &\qquad-[x^{2m^\prime+1}]\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{n-k}x^{2n+2k+3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m^{\prime}}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{m^{\prime}-k}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{m^{\prime}-2k}\\
> &\qquad -\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m^{\prime}-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{m^{\prime}-k-1}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{m^{\prime}-2k-1}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   Here we have $2m^\prime+1=2n+2k+1$ in the first summand and $2m^\prime+1=2n+2k+3$ in the second sum and we calculate similarly as we did in the even case.

**Conclusion:**

For even $m=2m^\prime$ we compare (1) with (3) and see the validity of the following binomial identity has to be shown
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m^\prime-1}
\binom{2m^\prime-k-1}{k}(ab)^{m^\prime-k-1}=
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m^{\prime}-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{m^{\prime}-k-1}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{m^{\prime}-2k-1}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

For odd $m=2m^\prime+1$ we compare (1) with (4) and see the validity of the following binomial identity has to be shown
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m^\prime}
\binom{2m^\prime-k}{k}(ab)^{m^\prime-k}&=
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m^{\prime}}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{m^{\prime}-k}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{m^{\prime}-2k}\\
&\qquad -\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m^{\prime}-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{m^{\prime}-k-1}{k}(-1)^k(ab+2)^{m^{\prime}-2k-1}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

> **Second step:**
>
> We prove the validity of the binomial identity (6) by showing that the odd powers of the generating function $G(x)$ of the left-hand side correspond with the odd powers of $F(x)$.
>
> We consider
>   \begin{align*}
> G(x)&=\sum_{m^\prime=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{m^\prime}\binom{2m^\prime-k}{k}(ab)^{m^\prime-k}x^{2m^\prime+1}\\
> &=x\sum_{m^\prime=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{m^\prime}\binom{2m^\prime-k}{k}(x\sqrt{ab})^{2m^\prime-2k}x^{2k}\tag{$2m^{\prime}-k=n$}\\
> &=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(x\sqrt{ab})^{n-k}(x^2)^k\\
> &=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(x\sqrt{ab}+x^2\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{x}{1-x\sqrt{ab}-x^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{G(x)+G(-x)}{2}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{1-x\sqrt{ab}-x^2}+\frac{x}{1+x\sqrt{ab}-x^2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{x(1-x^2)}{1-(ab+2)x^2-x^4}\\
> &=x+(ab+1)x^3+(a^2b^2+3ab+1)x^5+\cdots\\
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain a generating function consisting of the odd powers of $F(x)$. Similarly we can show the validity of (5).

Comment: @drxy: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty.